# Unable to install composer packages dependent on GD PHP extension in Docker Container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, gd

I an trying to create a dockerized network for my application. With my current `docker-compose.yml` configuration I am able to get everything up and running and working. The issue I am facing is when I am trying to install composer packages dependant on the GD extension. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with either my Dockerfile for PHP or my docker-compose network setup?

#### PHP Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-alpine

# Install php extensions
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev && apk add libzip-dev freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libpng-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql mbstring zip

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd

# Setup working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

#### Docker Compose PHP Network Block

```
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    networks:
      - testNetwork
```

Thanks in advance!!

Continued: When I shell into the running docker container, you can see the loaded docker-php-extensions.

```
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d # ls
docker-php-ext-gd.ini         docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini  docker-php-ext-sodium.ini     docker-php-ext-zip.ini
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d #
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do so, is [this](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) awesome project on github, easily replace:

```
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions gd
```

with your `Dockerfile`'s php extension installation section.

**Edit:**

You can also install composer on any docker container as easy as pasting:

```
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Comment: Hi, @eamirgh I have tried rebuilding my PHP Dockerfiel from this I am still getting the same result... I cannot install composer dependencies that required the GD extension. However, when I shell into the docker container all the extensions show up. So am I doing something with my Laravel setup that its not finding it?

Comment: I am able to connect to my Postgres Database and run tinker and migrations so some of the drivers must be working.

Comment: Where is your composer installed? in your locsl machine or docer container?

Comment: Composer is installed as its own docker container within my docker-compose.yml

Comment: You should put it on the php container.

Comment: Or if you do not want to install it on php container you should install the extensions on the composer container.

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git libonig-dev  libxml2-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libonig-dev curl mcrypt gnupg build-essential software-properties-common wget vim libwebp-dev

RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring pdo pdo_mysql tokenizer xml bcmath opcache pcntl intl soap exif gd
```

Try with above code snippet, for gd there are php-ext-configure install and install some lib like libpng-dev

Hope it will helpful for you